# how to use " as character in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, escaping, character

I need to use " and ' as a character in C#, however they are special characters. So when I put them as character in the string, it will give an error. The issue is that it has many " and ' so I need to find a way to allow me to use these special characters. How can I do that

Comment: You might find what you're looking for by using the words "escape" in google or even just the stack overflow search.  Try: "C# escaping"

Comment: See this question: How to add doublequotes to a string that is inside a variable? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905946/how-to-add-doublequotes-to-a-string-that-is-inside-a-variable

Comment: use an [at] like this: var mystring = @"my string includes a " character!" OR escape it with a backslash: var mystring = "my string contains a \" character!"

Answer (score 7):

Use escape sequences: `"This is a double-quote: \", and this is a single quote: \'"`

Although note that since the string is delimited by double quotes, the `\'` escape isn't necessary: `"This is a double-quote: \", and this is a single quote: '"`

Comment: A single quote doesn't need to be escaped, unless you're trying to get the single quote `char`: `'\''`

Answer (score 3):

Simple prefix your string with `@` for `"` use `""`  This makes newlines easy as pie:

```
string example = @"A string that has double quote "" and single quote ' also a new line
     ";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use escape character  `\`

Example

```
var testSTring = "\"test\""
```

Answer (score 1):

Having a single quote `'` in string doesn't trouble C#, its the double quotes `"`, you have to **escape them with backslash** like:

```
 string str = "some\"stri'''''ng";
```

You can also use [verbatim string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx) `@` in the start and then you have to escape double quotes with another double quote like:

```
string str = @"some""stri'ng";
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a backslash before special chars you want to use to escape them.

Here's a list:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx