# C# passing quotes in string

Tags: c#, string, powershell

I am trying to pass quotes in string. I am having a hard time formulating the code.

```
path = path.Insert(0, @"\\ffusvintranet02\picfiles\temp\");
string format = "Set-UserPhoto ";
format += "" + user + "";
format += " -PictureData ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes(";
format += "" + path + @"";
format += ")";
```

The user and path are variables that needs to be inside single quotes for the AD Command. command. What I have isn't working.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905946/how-to-add-doublequotes-to-a-string-that-is-inside-a-variable

Comment: your problem is that the @ sign stops \ meaning escape. Use ""

Answer (score 1):

User `\"` for `"` symbol or `\'` for `'`

```
format += "\"" + user + "\"";
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all , use `string.format` for such tasks. Second you have to escape quotes ( but you dont need to escape single quotes).

Double quotes can be escaped by double quote or by backslash based on type of string literal you are using:

```
var s = @"something "" somethin else ";  // double double quote here

var s2 = "something \" somethin else ";
```

Now, using `string.format`, your code will turn into:

```
 path = path.Insert(0, @"\\ffusvintranet02\picfiles\temp\");
 string format = string.format("Set-UserPhoto {0} -PictureData ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes(\"{1}\")", user, path);
```

or

```
 path = path.Insert(0, @"\\ffusvintranet02\picfiles\temp\");
 string format = string.format(@"Set-UserPhoto {0} -PictureData ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes(""{1}"")", user, path);
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string format = "Set-UserPhoto "; format += "'" + user + "'"; format += " -PictureData ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("; format += "'" + path + @"'"; format += ")";
```

Comment: `'" + user + "'` doesn't compile

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using string interpolation within a here-string as follows, this will prevent you from having to use string concatenation and escaping.

```
$format = @"
Set-UserPhoto " + user + " -PictureData ([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes(" + path + ")"
"@
```