# Formula to specific cell

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula

My question is as follows.

How can I apply the following excel formula
`=COUNTIF('OtherSheet'!A2:A1500,"<>"&"")` to a specific cell, via `C#` code?

I ask this because i can't use my following code because of the multiple.

Code as follows:

```
xlWorkingSheet.Cells[4, 2].Formula = "=COUNTIF('OtherSheet'!A2:A1500,"<>"&"")";
```

Any sort of help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can add a `"` to your string like this: `\"`. Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905946/how-to-add-doublequotes-to-a-string-that-is-inside-a-variable) for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the below solution:

```
xlWorkingSheet.Cells[4, 2].Formula = "=COUNTIF('OtherSheet'!A2:A1500,\"<>\"&\"\")"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, at first I kept trying to use \ but i was doing it wrong.
Thank you very much.