# double quotes not coming in fileName while using Response.AddHeader

Tags: javascript, asp.net

When using

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName)
```

double quotes in fileName gets converted to -. Any suggestion how to use double quotes in fileName ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905946/how-to-add-doublequotes-to-a-string-that-is-inside-a-variable

Comment: filename can't have the following characters:\ / : * ? " < > |". that's why I was unable to add these characters in file name.

Comment: yes..sorry overlooked that point.. the solution was for generating string with quotes.. :/