# Chr(34) equivalent

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am converting `VB.NET` code to `c#` and I am stopped when I reached the following code snippet. I need someone's help to convert Chr(34). Please help me to convert it to `c#`.

**VB.NET Code**

```
Dim inputString As String
inputString = "Some text ..."
inputString = Replace(inputString, Chr(34), "")**
```

**My c# conversion is**

```
string inputString = "Some text ...";
inputString = inputString.Replace(NEED HELP HERE, "");**
```

Comment: You have choices you can use an escape so put a backslash or you can (char)34

Comment: 34 is `"` so replace with `"\""`

Comment: yep - its as simple as that - See Willem who has bother to write out more detail

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add double quotes to a string that is inside a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905946/how-to-add-double-quotes-to-a-string-that-is-inside-a-variable)

Comment: For what it's worth, using `Chr(34)` in VB ought to be discouraged, since it's lengthy and not very readable.  The way to escape a double-quote character in a string literal in VB is to put two in a row, so the equivalent would be `Replace(inputString, """", "")`.

Comment: And the equivalent for that would be `Replace(inputString, @"""", "")`

Comment: Wow, I can not believe this question received this much attention when honestly it is something you should already know before asking this type of question... I mean there is only over 430k hits on Google?.?

Comment: @Codexer Wonders of the World #8 : StackOverflow :D

Comment: @o_O no doubt about that... :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can cast an integer to a `char`, so an "automatic" translation would be:

```
inputString = inputString.Replace(, ((char) 34).ToString(), "")
```

That being said, the characters that maps to 34 (according to ASCII) is `"`, so you can simply construct a string with the double quote char:

```
inputString = inputString.Replace(, "\"", "")
```

This will also improve readability, since it is now clear what you are doing in that part: you remove double quotation characters.

Comment: Sure that works because Chr(**34**) is always returns [U+0022](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html). But in general, casting works for the range 0 to 255 yet is correct for the whole range 128 to 255 only if the user's (thread's) ANSI code page (ACP) is 28591 (ISO 8859-1).  Too many gotchas to recommend. Of course, that assumes that using `Chr` isn't a latent bug to begin with.

Answer (score 5):

Converted code below:

```
string inputString = null;
inputString = "Some text ...";
inputString = Strings.Replace(inputString, Strings.Chr(34), "");
```

I would recommend to use any converter if you are not dealing any confidential details. This will save sometime.

In fact, I used [this](http://converter.telerik.com/) tool to convert your code.