# Double Block Quote with String not working

Tags: c#, double-quotes

I have tried to insert a dynamic string in a static string with double quote, also tried [How to add double quotes to a string that is inside a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905946/how-to-add-double-quotes-to-a-string-that-is-inside-a-variable/3905970) but nothing work in my case:

```
startInfo.Arguments = @"/C = """+service+""" >nul 2>&1";
```

**service** is dynamic string and i need this result:

```
"/C = "mystring" >nul 2>&1";
```

Without dynamic variable i use double quote and it work, and i need **@** for static Path

```
"/C = ""static"" >nul 2>&1";
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The verbatim string only applies to the first part because you are concetanating with `+`, you can try using string interpolation:

```
startInfo.Arguments = $@"/C = ""{service}"" >nul 2>&1";
```

Comment: Thanks so much, you saved my life =)

Answer (score 2):

`if (your c# version < c#6)` use [`string.Format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.2) method:

```
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"/C = ""{0}"" >nul 2>&1", service);
```

you still can use `+` if you want:

```
startInfo.Arguments = @"/C = """+ 111 +"\" >nul 2>&1";
```

or even:

```
startInfo.Arguments = @"/C = """+ 111 + @""" >nul 2>&1";
```