# String interpolation add quotes around a word

Tags: c#, double-quotes, string-interpolation

I am trying add quotes in between `eventTime` variable. But  getting compile time error for both code statements below.

**Code:**

```
string message  = string.Format("Your event # {0}, is started at "{1}" in Texas.", eventId, eventTime);

string message  = $"Your event # {eventId}, is started at " + {eventTime} + "  in Texas.";
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Your event # 1, is started at "2" in Texas.
```

This may be simple, But I am not able to find proper syntax for this.

Any help would be Great.

**Note:**

Because of down votes , I know I have to escape double quotes so I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905946/how-to-add-double-quotes-to-a-string-that-is-inside-a-variable) post and tried to escape , But it failed. So I posted the question to know proper syntax. Thanks to all , this helped me to learn , so below is my answer:

Using [verbatim string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim).

```
string message  = $@"Your event # {eventId}, is started at ""{eventTime}""  in Texas.";
```

Hope helps someone.

Comment: You're missing the backslash escape before the quotes.

Comment: This isn't a string interpolation issue. All you need to do is to escape the quotes within the string.

Comment: $@"Your event # {eventId}, is started at ""{eventTime}""  in Texas."

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question? It may be a duplicate, but the question is clear. Questions [shouldn't be downvoted because they are duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62819/should-we-downvote-duplicates), and they certainly shouldn't be downvoted just because you think the OP should know the answer...

Comment: @John , Thanks  for the advice, But I think this question is partially duplicate , I know about escaping the double quotes but didn't know were to add it correctly. By the way I found a solution myself and added as answer in the question because I cant add it as answer.

Comment: When escaping quotes with the backslash, it includes the backslash in the output. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the escape character `\` like this:

```
string message = $"Your event # {eventId}, is started at \"{eventTime}\" in Texas.";
```

`message` then contains

```
Your event # 1, is started at "2" in Texas.
```

given that `eventId == 1` and `eventTime == 2`.

The escape sequence `\"` marks the quoatation marks part of the string, thus not terminating it.

Comment: Thanks you, Appreciate ! , I saw this but didint use this becuase i was after [verbatim string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim). I have added the solution to my question it self because i cant add it as answer because someone has marked as duplicate.

Comment: @BluE not sure what you mean... "output" as in console output? or are you looking at the string in the VS debugger? See [this](https://sharplab.io/#gist:a0ce900657123125315dee695d8f185d) for an example of the correct output.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow I was referring to the Rider immediate window, where it printed different (wrong) output apparently.

Answer (score 0):

You need the escape characters 
Please follow this link 
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available/

```
string message  = string.Format("Your event # {0}, is started at \"{1}\" in Texas.", eventId, eventTime);
```