# Double slash not working correctly in string C#

Tags: c#, string

I have been having a problem. When I put a double slash in a string with more strings inside, it goes crazy. Take a look. How do I fix this?

Photo:

[image]

Comment: Please copy-and-paste the lines of problematic code into the question. It is much easier for you, and it is less likely that vital parts of the code get cropped off in some screen grab.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add double quotes to a string that is inside a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905946/how-to-add-double-quotes-to-a-string-that-is-inside-a-variable)

Comment: The slashes are not the problem. The quote inside a string literal are the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape double quotes inside such a string literal. So:

```c#
loadstring("game:HttpGet(\"https://insert/url/here\")");
```

Without escaping (the `\` character) your double quotes inside the string literal say "the string ends here."