# Conditional Formatting C# AND Statement Blank not working

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to add conditional formatting to my VSTO Excel C# Application. I want to set the cell background colour to red if the column value in AH is the same as the column value in X and if X is not blank. However it complains at the below code saying

> Syntax error ',' expected.

This formula works fine when I manually put it in excel.

This is my formula: `=AND(X7=AH7,X7<>"")`

And here's my C# code:

```
FormatCondition format7 =
    (FormatCondition)(uiWorksheet.get_Range("AH7:AH" + lastUsedRow, Type.Missing)
        .FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression,
            XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual, "=AND(X7=AH7,X7<>"")",
           Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing));

format7.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

Comment: You need to escape those `"` in the formula: `"=AND(X7=AH7,X7<>\"\")"`

Comment: the Char `"` is a string delimiter. If you want to have `"` in your string you have to escape it. [How to add double quotes to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905946/)

Comment: Did that solve your issue? @xdtTransform- would you be open to posting that solution as an answer?