# How to use this regex filter string in regex in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex string "`(\"\--[a-zA-Z]+\")`" but I can not use it since it uses a double quotation.
What are the escape characters I could try here?

I want to use as follows in C# code to filter the "KernalSize"  from the following string :

```
parser.add_argument("--KernalSize", default = 6, help = "Noise removal")
```

Following filter `(\"\--[a-zA-Z]+\")` returns `"--KernalSize"`. However, when I try to set the filter in C# code, it failed due to a double quotation sign within the string.

```
const string ParamNameFilter = @"(\"\--[a-zA-Z]+\")";
```

Comment: Like this? `string pattern = @"""--([a-zA-Z]+)""";`

Comment: There is generally no problem to have `"` in C# string literal or string in general. Could you please [edit] question to clarify what you mean "can not use it since it uses a double quotation"?

Comment: @Thefourthbird that is no different from what OP has already... (as "" and \" are resulting in the same value...) can you please clarify why you think it is better?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I did not say I think that it is better, it was a question if that would work.

Comment: @Thefourthbird sorry, you are right. OP simply need to read (censored, suggesting to read documentation is unacceptable) about string literals and difference between`@".."` and `"..."`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov No worries, all is well :-)

Comment: Also, an exact dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905946/how-to-add-double-quotes-to-a-string-that-is-inside-a-variable

Comment: What was the _typo or not reproducible_ items in the post ? Was it really closed for that ?

Comment: @Maxt8r there are plenty ways to mistype string :) also it is mostly "While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers." Indeed it could be closed as duplicate instead as Wictor found... but generally questions are not re-opened just to be closed with different reason. Feel free to bring this to meta if you need more discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two quoting options are

Double quote `"(\"--[a-zA-Z]+\")"`

Verbatim `@"(""--[a-zA-Z]+"")"`

Note inside a verbatim string, the double quote is escaped by double quoting it.

Answer (score 1):

so your regex string `(\"\--[a-zA-Z]+\")` should match strings like `"--AnythingAlpha"`?

in reality the backslash before one of the `-` is not even necessary, so it begs a question if there is any type of a typo there, as it is equivalent to just `(\"--[a-zA-Z]+\")` or even a simpler `(\"--[a-z]+\")` with case-insensitive flag.

Now it's just about representing this string in C# strings:
`(\"\--[a-zA-Z]+\")` => to one of

- `@"(\""\--[a-zA-Z]+\"")"`
- `"(\\\"\\--[a-zA-Z]+\\\")"`

you can test them with something like:

```
  public static void Main (string[] args) 
  {
    Console.WriteLine(@"(\""\--[a-zA-Z]+\"")");
    Console.WriteLine("(\\\"\\--[a-zA-Z]+\\\")");
  }
```