# c# string builder adding " char

Tags: c#, html, .net

i want to know how to insert umlaut(") to **StringBuilder**..

**TEXT in HTML :::**

```
<iframe src ="navigation.html" linkTarget = "iframe">
```

**C#**

```
StringBuilder htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<iframe src = 'navigation.html' linkTarget = 'iframe'>")
```

With **'navigation.html'** html not working correctly ... i need Append **"navigation.html"** ,

I want to hear a lot of yours ideas how it could be made ...

Like using chars .. etc.. :)

Comment: You might want to edit your question - `"` isn't an umlaut, it's just double quotes. I found it very confusing for a while.

Comment: or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905946/how-to-add-double-quotes-to-a-string-that-is-inside-a-variable

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just missing the option of using `\` to escape the double quote within a string literal:

```cs
htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<iframe src=\"navigation.html\" linkTarget=\"iframe\">");
```

Comment: Hey ! Great, Thank You For Remind Me :)