# how to insert double quote in variable string c#

Tags: c#

I want to place a double quotes inside a string but it seems I got an error.
Someone can help me?

```
var User = user.Password;
string body = @"\" + User + ""\";
```

Comment: You almost got it. But please search. This was asked over 10 years ago.

Comment: `@"""" + User + @""""` or `"\"" + User + "\""` or I prefer: `$"\"{User}\""` and of course this last `$@"""{User}"""`.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? [How to add double quotes to a string that is inside a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905946/how-to-add-double-quotes-to-a-string-that-is-inside-a-variable) and [Escape double quotes in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480724/escape-double-quotes-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

For this you need to write below code.

```
var User = user.Password; 
string body = "\"" + User + "\"";
```